# Access to multiple desktops remotely

Tags: video, remote, sharing, projector

I would like to know if there is a way to create a script to access multiple desktops remotely. I would have a projector connected to a single machine and I would like to display different desktops in this projector based on some events in each source machine. I just want to display the video, I don't need access to the system of each single machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this, DisplayHost is connected to projector, HostA and HostB are remote machines; if something happens in HostA, it comes to the fore in DisplayHost ; then if something happens in HostB, then DisplayHost somehow would know to switch to displaying HostB ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will have two different games streaming in a projector, one at time. If a specific event happens in one of the games (I am working with the dev of the game so I can create events in order to specify these situations) I would like to display it on the projector. The same is valid for the HostB (the other game running in another PC). Therefore, I would have an automatic way to display the game of interest in my projector (DisplayHost, third PC).

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends what do you mean by

> if something happens

You have to notify *DisplayHost* about the event in order for it to grab a remote video stream.

What is a source of a video?

What you might want to do is just forward X output to *DisplayHost*. You can find part of the answer here: [Enabling SSH and Remote Desktop Access](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop)

In that case you can send a message to *DisplayHost* and trigger it's connecton to *HostA* or *HostB*

P.S. I assume that *HostA* and *HostB* both are producing video streams and *DisplayHost* is connected to a projector.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question about the source of the video, but it will be two PCs (HostA and HostB then) connected in a local network with another PC connected to a projector. In this way I want to access OR the HostA desktop (basically replicate what they see in their desktop) OR HostB. I will take a look in your link and then I will do an update here. Thanks.

Comment: @CristianSchneider I was asking will it be a video player or other application. You can stream application window to another PC if needed (but it is a bit complicated rather than vNC session). The main issue in your question is what triggers the connection. You can't stream from HostA or HostB if nothing will accept it on DisplayHost.

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment to the other tread, but `I am working with the dev of the game so I can create events in order to specify these situations` you have to pass the event to syslog or other even to the shell so it can be handled by script or other program on HostA or HostB to trigger other system-related events.

Comment: For example, your game will write some code like `Have-to-switch-host` to syslog and a cron job can monitor continuously if any such entry occur. If such entry has been detected the job than starts a script to make connection.

Comment: And you have to close connection from one host prior to open it for another. So task is not simple at all, but we have everything that needed for it to be real on a stock system.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that you can log a syslog message from the game mentioned there is a way to make all work.

On both HostA and HostB run a simple line under underprivileged user (i.e. not root)

For HostA

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/syslog | awk '/CHANGE-FOCUSE/ { print | "sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@DisplayHost killall -9 vncviewer &&  DISPLAY=:0 vncviewer -display 0 HostA:12345 && exit" }'
```

For HostB

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/syslog | awk '/CHANGE-FOCUSE/ { print | "sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@DisplayHost killall -9 vncviewer && DISPLAY=:0 vncviewer -display 0 HostB:12345 && exit" }'
```

where:

- CHANGE-FOCUSE - is a message generated by your game
- DisplayHost - IP or DNS name of your host with projector
- USER - a user account under which XSession is running (i.e. whose desktop you are using for projecting)
- PASSORD - a password of that user (it is not the safest setup, but simplest to test
- HostA - IP address or DNS name of a HostA
- HostB - IP address or DNS name of a HostB

P.S. You can play with vncviewer parameters to make window  full screen or so.

Also I **strongly recommend** make certificate authentication over SSH in order not to use plain text passwords [look here for details](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server).

- *sshpass* is a standalone utility that you have to install in order for plain text password to work with SSH as it is now deprecated.

Comment: And as the lest command is EXIT you have to find suitable way to monitor if that line is running in the system. You can make the script with provided line a service and that system will check it for you automatically.